# Detect FaceID support of an iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, touch-id, face-id

I try to detect the biometric capabilities of an iPhone like this:

```
let authenticationContext = LAContext()

switch authenticationContext.biometryType 
{ case LABiometryType.typeFaceID:
  print("faceID")
  case LABiometryType.typeTouchID:
  print("touchID")
  case LABiometryType.none:
  print("no biometric")
}
```

In Xcode 9 I get in the iPhone-X and iPhone 8 Simulator "LABiometryType.none" instead of expected LABiometryType.typeFaceID and LABiometryType.typeTouchID

Is that the correct way to detect Face-ID?

(It´s not about detecting an iPhone X (future iPhones will probably also support Face-ID)

Comment: Look into the hardware Menu of the Simulator. There you can simulate successful and not successful touchID and faceID authentication. TouchID testing works fine for me,

Comment: I don´t think the question is a duplicate. support of face-ID has not much to do with detecting an iPhone-X, assuming that many apple devices in the future will support face-ID.

Comment: My question is: Is the way described in the post correct, even if it doesn't´t work in the simulator (maybe a Bug?)

Comment: It's a bug. You need to use Xcode 9.1 (which is currently in beta) for this to work.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate at all